# Convert function argument into function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have this code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func( str CHARACTER VARYING ) RETURNS CHARACTER VARYING 
AS $$

BEGIN
    str := CAST(str AS INTEGER);

    IF  str > 4 THEN
        RETURN 'YES';
    ELSE
        RETURN 'NO';
    END IF;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, when  call this function `SELECT test_func('9')`

returned error:  `operator does not exist: character varying > integer`

Why this hapened? why `str` is not converted as `INTEGER` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did cast to integer as you asked it to. But then it did an automatic conversion to varchar as that is the `str`'s type. Do it like this:

```
IF str::int > 4 THEN
```

Answer (score 2):

This is broken by design.

If the value handed to the function is a valid `integer`, the parameter should be of type `integer` to begin with. Else the cast inside the function body will raise an exception sooner or later.
It should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(str integer) ...
```

Then you don't need any casting.

And - as long as it's simple as the test case - use an SQL function with a `CASE` statement or a plain SQL query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(str int)
  RETURNS text AS
$$
SELECT CASE WHEN str > 4 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END;
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Note that you can't refer to parameter *names* in *SQL functions* before Postgres 9.2. Use the positional parameter `$1` in older versions.